# cv2.matchShapes() return 0 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am having problem because with cv2.matchShapes() return 0 i am using opencv version 4.2 . I am trying to match the two same images as well as two different images but the prooblem is that it `returns 0`

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
img_1=cv2.imread('noise/1.png',0)
img_2=cv2.imread('noise/2.png',0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_1, 127, 255, 0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_2, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 2, 1)
cnt1 = contours[0]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2, 2, 1)
cnt2 = contours[0]
ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt1, 1, 0.0)
print(ret)
```

or either this

```
ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt2, 1, 0.0)
print(ret)
```

Comment: do you mean `cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt2, 1, 0.0)`?

Comment: You are doing `cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt1, 1, 0.0)`. Notice it should be `cnt1` and `cnt2` because you are matching to different contours list

Comment: Why did you expect that it returns something different (and what)?

Comment: in both cases it returns 0 with cnt1 and cnt2

Comment: And you're sure they are different images?

Comment: I am editing it here wait see the two images

Comment: @cwalvoort please read the question i have edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is something definitely wrong here. And it has to do with:

```
cnt1 = contours[0]
# ...
cnt2 = contours[0]
```

You are assuming there are only two contours found. So, if you do:

```
import numpy as np
    
#....your code 

for c in contours1:
    img_test = np.zeros(img_1.shape)
    img_test  = cv2.drawContours(img_test , [c], -1, (1), thickness=-1)
    cv2.namedWindow("c", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("c", img_test )
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You get:

[image: contour1]

As you can see, there are two contours found. If you do the same for `contours2` you get:

[image: contour2]

There are two contours as well for the second image. So in your code you are doing:

```
cnt1 = contours[0]
# ...
cnt2 = contours[0]
```

So you are trying to match the first contours on both image with as you can see from the images above are just kind of a dot. And that's why you get a result value of `0` -> They are the same.

So, you need to keep in mind that you are comparing the right contours. In this case you can see there are only just to contours an could check visually, but you could have several contours and must come up with something to filter them out and choose which ones to compare. In this case you know, so you could do:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img_1 = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
img_2 = cv2.imread('2.png', 0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_1, 127, 255, 0)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_2, 127, 255, 0)
contours1, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 2, 1)

cnt1 = contours1[1]
contours2, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh2, 2, 1)

cnt2 = contours2[1]
ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt2, 1, 0.0)

print(ret)
```

In this case, you would be comparing the right contours.

**Outputs:**

`15.69319078874479`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the variables you are using to be distinct, that way you aren't messing with any existing pointers:

```
c1, h1= cv2.findContours(thresh, 2, 1)
cnt1 = c1[0]
c2, h2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2, 2, 1)
cnt2 = c2[0]
ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt1, cnt2, 1, 0.0)
```

Comment: Ah, it wasn’t the whole problem but was part of it :)